# How to add a box for list items?

Tags: plugins, list

I need to add a box so a client can put their own images onto a carousel type slideshow, javascript just outputs the li of each instance it finds.

However I cant find a way to create a box where the user can just press enter, add an image, press enter, add an image etc. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want it using wordpress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an option page with image upload/select fields you can use the [Option Framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/) plugin. It is straighforward and easy to use for anyone.

If you want to add upload/select fields to a wordpress page or post use [Custom Fields Creator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-fields-creator/screenshots/) or the more powerful plugin: Advanced Custom Fields. NB you have to buy the [Repeater Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) add-on to be able to use one custom field as many times as you or your client want on a page or post.